# What is the keyboard shortcut for selecting option or at least jumping to the VSCode dialogues?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, dialog, user-experience

When something like this appears and I want to select Overwrite without clicking, how to do it?
Especially on Windows 10.
[image: fucking dialogue]

I can't believe that I can't find a result for that, maybe googling unlucky keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can focus the toasts using `notifications.focusToasts`. This was [added in version 1.21](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21#_new-commands). There's also `notifications.focusFirstToast` and `notifications.focusLastToast`.

There's also a command ID called `notification.acceptPrimaryAction` that might be what you want, depending on whether the action you want to accept is the primary action or not.